# How do you prevent client side console hacks on firebase web apps?

Tags: firebase

It dawned on me that with so much client side logic, malicious users can spoof, override or game firebase apps by using the console in any browser.

For instance, I can enter $(".flag").click() and with three strokes flag every post out of existence on my  app.

Any defensive logic I write will all be available to anyone who wants to crack it.

How have you dealt with this? Is there a work around?

Comment: You cannot prevent people from using their console. Use server-side.

Comment: Throttle the number of flags/updates from any given user to some absolute limit, or to some limit/minute.  Detect by cookie, browser id, ip address, or whatever user identity you care to use.

Comment: Firebase security rules can prevent users from changing data you don't want them to be touching: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reality, Firebase is no different than any other server process with regards to security. Anybody can open the JavaScript console on any site (or write their own HTML page, or run curl from the command line) to try to manipulate data.

Firebase moderates clients using straightforward but surprisingly powerful [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html). Couple those with an authentication schema, and you can restrict access to, and validate any incoming data with minimal fuss.

```
{
   "rules": {
       // widgetName must be a string
       "widgetName: { ".validate": "newData.isString()" },

       // user accounts can only be read by the authenticated client
       "users": {
           "$user_id": {
               ".read": "$user_id === auth.id"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting comments and answer. I have delved into the security rules recently and see where I think you are pointing at. the validate expression can be more than just checking auth matches and the like. It could check for timestamp differences or any other comparison I come up with. for example, same user with timestamps of less than 500ms or similar.

As usual, it take a lot of tar to make something water tight.

Comment: I wonder if the following example scenario can happen:

Let's say I have a blog and I present in every page 10 posts for authenticated users.

If the one authenticated user visits the url http://mydb.firebase.com/posts .. will they see all of my 200 current posts?

Will they have access to view nodes that I would not like to? Like users who "liked" the post?

If yes how can I prevent them for accessing the url?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase rules is really a new web building approach. You can build any kind of web app using thoses rules. 
I'll not put rules code here but I'll explain what I mean.
For example. You want to build a learning app. using rules you can create two or three roles for users. Then for each content you can put a field(array for example) and check for each request if the requester user after authentication have the role to access some content.
I think all CMS are working by this way right now.

Hope this will give more ideas on Firebase platform.