# Is Firebase form-validation server-side? How does it prevent circumvention?

Tags: javascript, validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say I'm building a web app that requires form validation. I'd like to use Firebase for my data layer. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data), this can be done with Database Rules, which are specified in a JSON document:

> Firebase Database Rules are made up of Javascript-like expressions contained in a JSON document.

My question is, what is preventing a malicious person from modifying the Database Rules document, and then submitting unvalidated data to the form and into the database? The documentation explains it as follows:

> Firebase Database Rules are declarative configuration for your
>   database. This means that the rules are defined separately from the
>   product logic. This has a number of advantages: clients aren't
>   responsible for enforcing security, buggy implementations will not
>   compromise your data, and perhaps most importantly, there is no need
>   for an intermediate referee, such as a server, to protect data from
>   the world.

I don't doubt the documentation, but I don't understand how the listed advantages work. How does specifying rules declaratively in a JSON document prevent hackers from modifying the rules, and then submitting bad data?

Comment: ["These rules live on the Firebase servers "](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). If the JSON document is on your server, how would hackers get access to it? (If they can get that far they probably don't need to be submitting things from a browser...) See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237836/how-do-you-prevent-client-side-console-hacks-on-firebase-web-apps) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380591/is-firebase-supposed-to-run-on-the-client).

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm still getting up to speed on Firebase. I did not know where the rules document lived and was under the impression that Firebase was more strictly for data only.

Comment: I don't know specifically where it lives, but the doco page I linked to seems to be saying it is server-side. It would have to be, or as you've said it wouldn't be secure at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn If you post as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I might just delete this question.